# Jmeter Scenario: Users Login once - pause until all logged in and execute process (based on iterations not time) - processes complete users log out

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins, stress-testing

I'm relatively new to Jmeter but I have a scenario that I've not been able to figure out where I need to perform the following:

All user log in to application with a ramp-up period of 15 seconds between users.
No activity continues until all users log in to application.
Once all users are logged in, perform their set of business activities (will vary depending on business process, and based on iterations, not a time loop).
Once all users are complete business processes, users begin to logout with ramp-down time of 15 seconds between users.
Is this possible to configure my script to execute this way and if so, how? I have tried use of Once only controllers, loop controllers, constant timers, and some various plugins (Custom Thread Groups). I've also viewed various threads and not been able to find this exact scenario, but cannot imagine this is an overly unique test case...

Any recommendations or advice is appreciated.

Thanks!

This is highlighted in question above

Answer (score 0):

1. Ramp-up period can be easily configured using "normal" [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group)
2. To "wait" until all the users are logged in use [Synchronizing Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer)
3. Use [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) to run the "business activities" as many times a you want
4. The same to wait until all the users finish executing their "business activities"
5. To implement ramp-down you can use [JSR223 Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Timer) and the following code:

   ```
   return (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1) * 15000
   ```

   where `ctx` stands for [JMeterContext](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html), see JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).